# $[a,b)$ is not open

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show [a,b) is not open. However, if i let $x \in (a,b) $ and set $\delta= min [|a-x|, |b-x|]$ then surely $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ is $\subset$ of $[a,b)$ $\forall x$?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you scanned?

Comment: Is the instructor looking for more/different discussion with the $B_a(\delta)$ term listed?  Is it possible that the usual notation is actually $B_\delta(a)$ instead?

Comment: Apologies, I did get confused by the notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the set $[a,b)$, there is a ball around any $x \in (a,b)$.  However, there is *no* ball around the point $x = a$, because that ball would have to contain points less than $a$.  A set is only open if **every** point has a ball around it contained in the set, so $[a,b)$ is not an open set.

Answer (score 2):

If $[a,b)$ is open then what interval around $a$ does it contain?

Comment: @usainlightning Do you think $\{0\}$ is open? Do you know what open means?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DaenerysNaharis This is the same exact answer as the other two, and the OP's image itself, only in the form of a rhetorical question. I checked your profile and you know enough topology to know that this is a rhetorical question aimed at helping the OP, not an independent irrelevant question asked by a noob (no offense to noobs) who can't find the "Ask a Question" link. You may not believe in the pedagogical value of rhetorical questions, but I don't appreciate the passive aggressiveness about it ("to critique or request clarification").

Comment: It appears that while this answer does point the OP in the right direction, it does so in a very terse, backwards way that does not necessarily help.  Perhaps you could expound on your answer a bit, at least enough to make the math.SE server not treat your answer as "possibly low quality"?

Comment: @abiessu Right after trying to answer my rhetorical question, OP made clear they thought open balls of radius zero (the empty set) around points counted in determining when sets are open. Misconceptions like that are important to bring to light. Then that comment was deleted (to which my reply remains), which presumably means OP is figuring out those don't count, and thereby coming to the correct conclusion. The reason I write terse answers, when I do, is to use the follow-up for back-and-forth as needed, if OP is willing, and to let them enjoy the individual challenge on the own, again

Comment: as needed. I have no illusions that this style is the best in all situations, or "necessarily" helps (that word choice imposes a strict standard). There would be no point in filling in the details at this point, as the other two answers already gave them away (they were posted later). I don't care what the server thinks. Also, with your word choice, doesn't "right direction" contradict "backwards way"?

Comment: I'm good with that, just trying to help with why you are getting negative feedback.  I meant "backwards" in the sense of sentence direction, as opposed to "right direction" for the overall content.  Just a little of my own "backwards" logic to throw in the mix.  :-)

Comment: @abiessu Thanks, I do appreciate that sentiment. I imagine the system caught the fact that a low-rep user made a one-line answer and didn't get any votes, so that put it into the review queue and these circumstances plus the power of suggestion lead to a delete vote and an ill-fitting boilerplate response.

Comment: @seaturtles I did not write that comment; it seems that the review system automatically makes such comments once it goes through the "low quality answers" queue. It doesn't help that basically the only two options upon reviewing are "looks good" and "is not an answer" (I clicked the latter since I missed the rhetorical value of your answer at first). I apologize in any case.

Answer (score 2):

If you take an open ball, $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ with $\epsilon>0$ and center it at $x$, for every $x\in[a,b)$ is it true that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset [a,b)?$  If it is then, $[a,b)$ is open. **Hint:**  look what happens when you center the ball at $a$.